# How to share globals between imported modules?

Tags: python, variables, global

I have two modules, a.py and b.py. I want the globals from a.py to be available in b.py like this:

a.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
var = "this is global"
import b
b.foo()
```

b.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
var = "this is global"
def foo():
    print var
```

Currently, I re-declare the globals in each module. There must be an easier way.

Comment: It makes no sense. You want `import a` on `b` and them `print a.var`

Comment: @JBernardo: No, that would cause a circular import.

Comment: @WilHall No it wouldn't because the `import b` should be removed. BTW, Python works with circular imports without complaining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a settings module that has shared globals if that's what you want. That way you're only importing and referencing each global one time, and you're keeping them isolated within the namespace of the settings module. It's a good thing.

```
#settings.py
var = 'this is global'

# a.py
import settings
import b
b.foo()

# b.py
import settings
def foo():
    print settings.var
```

Comment: Thanks all. Makes sense. Now need to do the work and search/replace my 85 modules (plugins).

Answer (score 2):

By making b.py require globals from a.py, you have created classes that depend on each other, which is bad design.

If you have **static** variables that need to be shared, consider creating **c.py** which both **a.py** and **b.py** can import and reference.

If you have **dynamic** variables that need to be shared, consider creating a **settings** class that can be instantiated and passed between the modules.

Answer (score 2):

Define your globals in c.py and import them into a.py and b.py