# Make global variables available in multiple modules

Tags: python, import, module

I am creating an application consisting of several modules. There is one main.py file which will be the file to run the application. The main.py file will load the configuration file(s) and put them in the 'config'-variable. It will also import the application-module-file (the file which holds the source-code of the application itself, a.k.a. application-class) and start the instance.

I am not very experienced in coding Python, and my biggest question is if I am doing it the right way, by using a main-file to handle all needed stuff (loading configuration-files for example). The problem I am having right now is that I cannot access the 'config'-variable that was defined in the main.py-file from any other module and/or Python-file.

Is it possible to make a global variable for configuration-values exc.? I know in PHP I used to create a singleton object which holds all the specific global arguments. I could also create a global 'ROOT'-variable to hold the full path to the root of the application, which is needed to load/import new files, this is also not possible in Python as far as I know.

I hope someone can help me out of this or send me in the right direction so I can continue working on this project.

Comment: Share the relevant code. Also globals are very bad: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Comment: In PHP you would use a singleton? Well, each Python module is a singleton. Create a `settings` module to handle the configuration data and import this module in every other module where you need it.

Comment: Due to private project I cannot yet share any code, but thanks for the comment.

@Matthias: Thanks for you reaction! That would mean that on every file I need the settings, I would have to import the settings-module and create a new settings-object. That will reload the whole configuration-file every time I do that, am I right? Or is it possible to make settings-module always return the same instance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to share globals between imported modules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743905/how-to-share-globals-between-imported-modules)

Comment: Another answer that fits your question and actually gives an example for the use case of global settings/configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/142601/2319400

Comment: @Benur Roptire: If you import a module a second time it is accessed from the internal list of already loaded modules. In the `settings` module you could check if the configuration data was already read (by a flag or something like that) and if not read the data (and set the beforementioned flag), else everything is fine.

Comment: Thank you all for the information! So if I should create a settings-module which then loads up the config-file and put: self._loaded = True. If I then import the same settings-module into another module or Pyton-file, it will be able to check if self._loaded == True? I should create a new object of the new imported settings-module if I'm right, or can I just call the same settings-module, and how?

Comment: You can simply use the `settings` module itself as the `settings` "object". Python will then automatically take care that the module, e.g. the config is only loaded once, at the first `import settings` invocation.

Comment: Thanks sebatian! But how can I use the settings module as the "object"? I import the module this way: from AppName.modules.settings import *.

Comment: @Benur Roptire: Use `from AppName.modules import settings` and then access the data in the module with `settings.value`. According to [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), the style guide for Python code, wildcard imports should be avoided and would in fact lead to undesirable behaviour in this case.

Comment: @Matthias: Is settings modules (function) or a class. Because a class seems more efficient for this matter. But I cannot do from modules.config import Config, where Config is the real classname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be by Matthias:

Use from AppName.modules import settings and then access the data in the module with settings.value. According to PEP-8, the style guide for Python code, wildcard imports should be avoided and would in fact lead to undesirable behaviour in this case.

Thanks you all for the help!